# CollectionView - Adding a new cell

Tags: ios, asynchronous, swift3, collectionview

I am working on an Note taking App. The User can create notes and store them on Dropbox. user will sign into Dropbox account and creates new notes which are then uploaded.
I have a collectionView and the add button takes the user to create a new note screen. This screen has a simple TextView to write/edit the text and a Save button.
When I create a new note and hit the Save button I exit and go back to the CollectionView and I want the new note to be appended to the CollectionView and the note will also be uploaded to DropBox as a text file.

I am using Dropbox API to fetch a list of file from the folder created in Dropbox account for this app. Once I get the list of files I store them in a String array and use that to populate the CollectionView.

This is working for existing files in the CollectionView but when I add a new note, should I insert the new note as a cell in the collectionView or does it get added when I call the collectionView.reloaddata() call.

Comment: First append new note in collectionViewDatasource array and then reload collection view or after updating collectionViewDatasource use     **collectionView.insertItems(at: [IndexPath])** method to update your collectionview.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new note, append/add it to the array you use to populate the collectionView. Then u can either use

```
 collectionView.reloadData()
```

or if you only want to update the collectionView, you can use,

```
 collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
```